# Add new product in Magento through REST API

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, post

I'm running Magento sample code for a REST API
(http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html)

I achieved a correct authentication, with an authentication token, and after the POST I got feedback of a correct upload with this message:

```
Array ( 
    [url] => http://magentohost.pt/magento/api/rest/products
    [http_code] => 200
    [download_content_length] => 37
    [content_type] => text/html
    [size_download] => 37
    [size_upload] => 250
)
```

However, the sent data doesn't appear in database/magento.

In any of the sample codes on the Magento API REST page, I get communication with the API but not the changes on products/customers data of the database.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create products using REST API

```
<?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Reference: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html#RESTAPIIntroduction-CreateasimpleproductasanAdminuserwithOAuthauthentication

Comment: I'm sorry but this was not very helpful since that is the code I am already using to make a POST, like I stated in my question.

Comment: Did you give the correct values for these two variables $consumerSecret, $consumerKey on top?

Comment: The credentials seem to be correct since using a rest client extension for chrome and making a GET request with the same OAuth authorization works fine. Also note that the response status code I get with the example is 200 so everything appears to have worked. However, no changes are noticeable on the database or anywhere else on the system.

Comment: In which table your are checking in the database?

Comment: catalog_product_entity "Catalog Product Table"